# Tools for tracing a program abortion

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, runtime-error

I have a program in C++ on an Ubuntu machine, that contains several threads, every thread is responsible for big amount of functions and sub functions.

The program runs, but every ~30 minutes the code stops running, I'm trying to understand why. So far I tried to:

1. Put `try-catch` all over the code: main and every thread - the program stops running without catching:

   ```
   try
   {
    //code
   }
   catch(const std::exception & e)
   {

   }
   catch(...)
   {

   }
   ```

2.Using `strace`: When the code stops running, the last lines of the output file are:

```
    nanosleep({0, 10000}, NULL)    = 0
    nanosleep({0, 10000}, NULL)    = 0
    nanosleep({0, 10000}, NULL)    = 0
    nanosleep({0, 10000}, NULL)    = 0
    nanosleep({0, 10000}, NULL)    = 0
    nanosleep({0, 10000}, NULL)    = 0
    nanosleep({0, 10000}, NULL)    = 0
    nanosleep({0, 10000}, NULL)    = 0
    nanosleep({0, 10000},  <ptrace(SYSCALL):No such process>
    +++ killed by SIGABRT +++
```

I cannot understand what causes the abortion of the program by `killed by SIGABRT` message or `<ptrace(SYSCALL):No such process>`

3. Using `gdb`: I put

   ```
   (gdb) catch throw
   (gdb) run
   ```

the code starts to run but it seems that the gdb stops running:

```
    Starting program: *****
    [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
    Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
    [New Thread 0x7ffff2d6a700 (LWP 13305)]
    [Thread 0x7ffff2d6a700 (LWP 13305) exited]
    [Inferior 1 (process 13304) exited normally]
    (gdb)
```

If I'm doing something wrong here, I'll be happy to know what is wrong and if not, are there some other ways\tools to trace the problem?

I'm starting to think maybe it something external to the program that causes this issue (?).

Thanks.

Comment: Does the program use a lot of memory? I'm thinking this might be the Linux "Out Of Memory Killer".

Comment: I thought so also, but it doesnt use too much memmory..

Answer (score 1):

Put breakpoints on everything that exits

```
b exit
b _exit
b __exit
b exit_group
```

And maybe also kill variants, if you don’t use them elsewhere

```
b kill
```

Comment: The thread isn't exiting, though. Maybe it kills itself, but there's `raise` for that.

Comment: Hi, I put some printouts before every exit but I dont see them while the program stops running.. Ill try to do the same with pthread_exit